# Hive Table Structure and Formats

Tags: hive

Can we have Constraints in Hive Tables.Is that Possible to have two tables as one table with Primary key column and another table as Foreign key column

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. This is getting into ways in which Hive differs greatly from a traditional RDBMS.

For instance, one crucial feature of Hive is that you can "load" data into it simply by adding files to an HDFS directory that is the underlying location of a Hive table. Since this operation does not use Hive at all, it would have no way of checking constraints for this new data.

Hive is first and foremost a batch processing system; this kind of row-level checks are not the focus at all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition what Joe K explained, note Hive is "Schema on Read", the underlying data would not complain when data is loaded using "load inpath" etc. Its only during read that the checks are done. what are you trying to accomplish?. The query seems to be more of a RDBMS requirement.

The reading schema could be different for the same underlying data. for example. Lets consider the following sample dataset (focus on the format)

```
Manufacturer | product | qty| list price
Manu1, CA| home, accessories | 12 | 73.11
Manu2, GA| mobile phone | 25 | 200
Manu3, TX| mattress | 3 | 1000
```

The hive table contents would change based on your create table syntax. Consider the basic create table below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE products (
manufacturer string,
product string,
qty double,
listprice double)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
location '<source location>'
```

In the fields terminated by if '|' is ignore or replaced by ',' the select on the table completely varies and that is where the checks happen and it fails if qty gets a string value.